# newbie: dummy JSON source?

Tags: jquery-ui

Im using a jquery ui's autocomplete, which require a "source". I want to get it to work with a remote datasource. So i tried creating `test.html` and added a json string

```
[
        {
            value: "1",
            label: "Hot'N'Sweet",
            desc: "124.00 SEK",
            icon: "ajax_productdummy_1.png",
            likes: "12"
        },
        {
            value: "2",
            label: "Tuborg Julöl",
            desc: "229.00 SEK",
            icon: "ajax_productdummy_2.png",
            likes: "2"
        },
        {
            value: "3",
            label: "Famous Grouse",
            desc: "449.00 SEK",
            icon: "ajax_productdummy_3.png",
            likes: "54"
        }
    ]
```

But when i specify "test.html" as source, nothing happens. Later on i will have an .ashx file returning a json string. But for now i want this dummy source. What did i miss?

Answer (score 2):

I think the JSON is invalid, When you run it through the validator at http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ it says the strings need double quotes (here, it's the variable names that are missing them). I think it should look like this:

```
[
   {
      "value":"1",
      "label":"Hot'N'Sweet",
      "desc":"124.00 SEK",
      "icon":"ajax_productdummy_1.png",
      "likes":"12"
   },
   {
      "value":"2",
      "label":"Tuborg Julöl",
      "desc":"229.00 SEK",
      "icon":"ajax_productdummy_2.png",
      "likes":"2"
   },
   {
      "value":"3",
      "label":"Famous Grouse",
      "desc":"449.00 SEK",
      "icon":"ajax_productdummy_3.png",
      "likes":"54"
   }
]
```

Hope this helps!